# Gradle missing from a project

Tags: java, android, github, gradle, clone

I downloaded a repo as zip from github, I had some VCS mapping error. I searched here and found a solution to clone the repo instead of downloading as a zip.
I cloned it and opened it in Android Studio. There are no errors or pop ups or anything but I can't find my gradle. I can't sync the project to gradle to enable me run the project. My gradle is missing on only that project. It works on any other project I have. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind linking to where you downloaded the repo from? I have a hunch, but it would be good to first confirm it's right by importing the project myself.

Comment: This is the link to the repo @TheRyanKing87
https://github.com/i-nazrul/Firebase-Realtime-Chat-app

Comment: That repository has no Gradle files. The owner should have pushed the build scripts and wrapper configuration along with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

> File -> New -> import project -> select your repository folder

Android studio will create gradle files for your project

Answer (score 0):

This project has several things in the way of getting it running. I was able to get it going with the below steps.

1 - Create a new project in Android Studio (File > New > New Project, Empty Activity should be fine). Reason for this is to generate a few files that the project is missing so we can copy them over.

2 - Go to the root folder of the project you just created (the folder with the "app", "gradle", and ".idea" folders in it).

3 - Download the project as a zip & extract. Open this project's root folder (similarly, the one with "app" and ".idea" folders in it).

4 - From the root folder of the project you created, copy four files and one folder - the build.gradle, gradle.properties, local.properties, and settings.gradle files and the gradle folder - to the root folder of this firebase project.

5 - It will recognize it as a gradle project and attempt to build, but it will fail because it doesn't recognize the 'com.google.gms.google-services' plugin. To fix this go to the project-level build.gradle file and under the line where it says "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'" add a line saying "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'".

6 - Some gradle configuration errors remain. This probably isn't the only configuration that would work, but it does seem to work and not require changes to the project's code: Go to File > Project Structure and set the gradle plugin version to be 3.0.0 & the gradle version to be 4.4. Then go to the module-level build.gradle folder and set the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 26. Also remove the "buildToolsVersion" line. Perform a gradle sync and it should be good to go! Weirdly, it didn't run on my emulator (not sure why), but did run on a physical device. Also, the app itself seems to have functional problems (seems unresponsive?). But that should at least get it running.